# background: url("/static/img/fauxColumns1.png") repeat-y ( -10px?)

Tags: css

I have the css code:

```
#container {
    background: url("/static/img/fauxColumns1.png") repeat-y;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
```

, applying to a div. This causes the div image to repeat to the bottom of the page.

At the top of the page I have a div:

```
#navbar {
    background-color: silver;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

, which successfully creates a margin below it of 10px.

However, I also have a div:

```
#footer {
    background-color: silver;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}
```

, but if I use '`margin-top: 10px`' this does not successfully create a margin, as the 'fauxColumns' extend to cover the gap.

So, does anyone know how to get around this?

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Tj3jH/1/
But, I don't know how to add my img files i.e. fauxColumns.png (I guess I have to upload it to some other site and link it?)
I tried to fix the problem with whiteLine10px.png but haven't gotten anywhere with that...

Comment: Hopefully we can answer your question this time, is it possible to get everything pertaining to your question in a www.jsfiddle.net ?  That way you'll get a faster and more accurate answer.

Comment: What effect do you expect `height: 100%;` to have in `#container`?

Comment: I removed your "load of unnecessary drivel". Please don't add irrelevant details to your questions, and please don't repost questions. Edit any new details into your previous questions.

Comment: I'm with @Fernker make a jsfiddle and post the link.

Comment: @Fernker If a JSFiddle is required to solve a problem, it's too localized for this site. Please stop asking for fiddle links. It's encouraging bad behaviour that we actively want to *avoid* on this site. JSFiddle links are meant to *supplement* questions only, not to be their primary content.

Comment: *chanting* [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)...

Comment: @meager I agree/disagree (many good points made here). The OP doesn't supply the layout of his page. We don't know what the parent or children elements are, making it difficult to tell what the problem is. I'm encouraging a JSFiddle, or a show of his HTML.

Comment: @meagar, I don't agree, CSS is a visual medium that requires live debugging in the browser to know exactly what is happening.  Looking at the code that is pasted can provide answers but a JSFiddle will help others understand the problem (and often cases can help the OP find the issue as they get the problem to replicate in a JSFiddle).  Also, I only ask for a JSFiddle when the question isn't clear on exactly what they need or what is happening.

Comment: height: 100% has no effect in #container you're correct; I didn't repost the question, the first one I just edited it, but I deleted because people didn't seem to like the question, and decided to have another go now, so of course I had to make a new question... I will try to make a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Fernker That's fine, but it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. That is why we have "too localized" close-votes. If a question can't be answered without a fiddle, it doesn't belong here. If you need clarification, ask for the question to be updated with additional code, not a JSFiddle link.

Comment: @meagar I don't think that's what too localized means.  To me, that's when people can duplicate the problem, thus is it is localized.  CSS is a very different medium than something like PHP.  I think if JSFiddles were so bad, and that is was such a huge problem, that StackOverflow wouldn't allow those links to be added.  Sorry but I'm going to keep asking for JSFiddle links when I feel they are needed to give the best clarification.

Comment: Quite frankly while jsFiddle might not be NEEDED for a question it makes it so much easier to help someone by using it.  I think it's quite silly to NOT provide one if it's requested.  I too request them if I can't simply look at what's provided... The simple act of moving code into a jsFiddle has helped me solve my own problems before simply by the fact that I had to look at each section again to move it into a fiddle.  There really isn't much of a difference between asking for additional code and asking for a jsFiddle....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike your response to @s_qw23 based on your fiddle `#footer` was in fact a child of container.

Moving `#footer` outside of `#container` fixes your issue. (I just used bing to grab a background image...while I doubt it will have an effect you will need to test to make sure)

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj3jH/2/)

Comment: Omg... I had it as child of the container earlier by accident but moved it out when I noticed, and somehow it moved back in. Maybe I over-clicked ctrl+z one time.. Oh man I thought I'd discovered an actual issue =/ Thanks a lot, I should have noticed it myself, but of course as I'd never done this scenario before and couldn't find any examples of it I was not sure it could even be done so simply - so I was looking at other ways around it rather than just thoroughly checking over my code. I mean I kept looking of course but not slowly enough, I will get more used to it with experience..

Comment: It happens...sometimes you just need an extra set of eyes.